# Firebase dependencies fails with Android Pie and new androidx.* package hierarchy

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I am starting a new project from the scratch. I would like to use all new libraries dependencies with new package structure. (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor)

Unfortunately I am not able to compile the project when firebase libraries are added.

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$FIREBASE_CLOUD_MESSAGING_VERSION"
```

Without libraries the project compiles, so the problem is with Firebase dependencies.

**The build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.60'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2' // google-services plugin

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION = '1.0.0-alpha1'
    CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT_VERSION = '1.1.2'
    PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = '12.0.1'
    MULTIDEX_VERSION = '2.0.0'
    ARCHITECTURE_COMPONENTS_VERSION = '2.0.0-alpha1'
    KOTLIN_KTX_VERSION = '1.0.0-alpha1'
    FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION = '16.0.1'
    FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION = '16.0.2'
    FIREBASE_CLOUD_MESSAGING_VERSION = '17.1.0'
}
```

**The app.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "googleapisportfolio"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        signApk {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['key.alias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['key.alias.password']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['key.store'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['key.store.password']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.signApk
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            buildConfigField("String", "GOOGLE_API_KEY", '"NA"')
            buildConfigField("String", "FIREBASE_ROOT_PATH", '"portfolio"')
            buildConfigField("String", "NA"')
            manifestPlaceholders = [places_api_key: "NA"]
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "google-apis-portfolio-${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:$SUPPORT_LIB_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$MULTIDEX_VERSION"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$ARCHITECTURE_COMPONENTS_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$ARCHITECTURE_COMPONENTS_VERSION"

    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$ARCHITECTURE_COMPONENTS_VERSION"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$KOTLIN_KTX_VERSION"

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$FIREBASE_CORE_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$FIREBASE_AUTH_VERSION"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$FIREBASE_CLOUD_MESSAGING_VERSION"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**The stacktrace:**

> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>     ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>     dex
>         at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeMultidex(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:266)
>         at com.android.builder.dexing.DxDexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(DxDexArchiveMerger.java:133)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:101)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ExternalLibsMergerTransform.transform(ExternalLibsMergerTransform.kt:123)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
>         at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
>         at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
>         at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
>         ... 29 more Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>     dex
>         at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:72)
>         at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:36)
>         ... 48 more Caused by: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/media/MediaDescriptionCompat;
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:660)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:615)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:597)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>         at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:197)
>         at com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerCallable.call(DexArchiveMergerCallable.java:61)
>         ... 49 more

**The build dependecies:**

```
releaseCompileClasspath - Resolved configuration for compilation for variant: release
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.60
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.60
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.2.60
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.60
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.60 (*)
+--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |         +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |         |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |         +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |         |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |         \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    +--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    |    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    \--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0-alpha1
|         +--- androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    \--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.transition:transition:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    \--- androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-alpha1
|         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|         +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|         \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2
|    \--- androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-solver:1.1.2
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    +--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:2.0.0-alpha1
|    |    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
|    \--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0-alpha1
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.41 -> 1.2.60 (*)
|    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-alpha1
|    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-alpha1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
|    |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
|    |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.1.1] -> 16.1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0 -> 16.2.0
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
|    |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0
|    |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1
|    |    |              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |              |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:16.0.1
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.1] -> 16.0.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.1.1] -> 16.1.1 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:16.0.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[16.2.0] -> 16.2.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0 (*)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: It may not help, but you could try the [1.0.0-beta-01 release of androidx](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn#1.0.0b01).

Comment: Not luck @BobSnyder In fact, today the have released a new version 1.0.0-rc01. Anyway thanks!

Comment: FWIW--My build differs from your in some ways, but I am able to build with the `androidx` libs and the same Firebase libs you have (plus others).  I forget all the steps I took to make that work.  In my `gradle.properties` I have `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`.  If you don't, you might need to explore if they are needed.  They are [explained here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#android_jetpack).

Comment: I already have this properties. I will check the doc again. Thanks!

Comment: @BobSnyder I have downloaded the new Android Studio 3.3 Canary 5 and works.

Comment: Always glad to hear of a successful outcome!